# Is there a way to pass header information in Spring RestTemplate DELETE call

Tags: java, spring, web-services, rest, resttemplate

In Spring `RestTemplate` we are having the following methods for delete.

```
@Override
    public void delete(String url, Object... urlVariables) throws RestClientException {
        execute(url, HttpMethod.DELETE, null, null, urlVariables);
    }

    @Override
    public void delete(String url, Map<String, ?> urlVariables) throws RestClientException {
        execute(url, HttpMethod.DELETE, null, null, urlVariables);
    }

    @Override
    public void delete(URI url) throws RestClientException {
        execute(url, HttpMethod.DELETE, null, null);
    }
```

None of these methods are having any place to pass header information. Is there any other method which can be used for `DELETE` request with header information?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You can use the `exchange` method (which takes any HTTP request type), rather than using the `delete` method:

```
MultiValueMap<String, String> headers = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
headers.add("X-XSRF-HEADER", "BlahBlah");
headers.add("Authorization", "Basic " + blahblah);
etc...

HttpEntity<?> request = new HttpEntity<Object>(headers);
restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.DELETE, request, String.class);
```

Comment: Are you sure this will work. As far as I know, HttpMethod.DELETE is not allowed to have a body.

Comment: It works fine for us.  It doesn't have a body: just headers, which are allowed in any HTTP message.

Answer (score 7):

You can implement `ClientHttpRequestInterceptor` and set it for your `restTemplate`. In your interceptor:

```
 @Override
public ClientHttpResponse intercept(
        HttpRequest request, byte[] body, ClientHttpRequestExecution execution)
        throws IOException {
        @Override
        public ClientHttpResponse intercept(HttpRequest request, byte[] body, ClientHttpRequestExecution execution) throws IOException {
            if (request.getMethod() == HttpMethod.DELETE){
                request.getHeaders().add(headerName, headerValue); 
             }

             return execution.execute(request, body);
        }
}
```

In your config:

```
restTemplate.setInterceptors(...)
```

Comment: This is a better solution when you need to add the header to lots of calls or every call. It's much less code.